# C++ program that behaves differently depending on a semicolon

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write two legal C++ programs A and B such that I can get B from A by deleting (or moving) a single semicolon (at a token boundary) but A and B show different behavior when compiled and executed?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Indeed, the semicolon is a separator, just place one just after the "for" or "while" loop and you will see

Comment: I'm just curious, I'm not trying to achieve anything.

Comment: Sure.  Put a `;` right after a loop like `while(something); {stuff}`.

Comment: @GabrielVince: Terminator, actually. It's a separator in Pascal. The difference is that the last statement in a block doesn't need a separator, but it does need a terminator. Research has shown that programmers make less errors with terminators than they do with separators, so the distinction is important.

Comment: How can this question be too broad if there is exactly one correct answer: "Yes, for example this program"? I guess it is a stupid question because the answer is so obvious, but it certainly is not broad.

Comment: Because there are many answers "Yes, for example this program", "Yes, for example this other program", etc.

Comment: @MartinBonner: You only need one example to demonstrate the answer, and it doesn't matter which example you choose.

Comment: That seems to be true for almost any question. You can always give equivalent answers that use slightly different words.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure.

```
int main() {
    if (0) ; // try removing the semicolon here
        return 7;
}
```

Look at the return value.